# I don't want to allow to goto the next step if user don't enter data in all the Required field in current page

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

**While moving from one step to another step, we have to validate the current step fields. But it validating all steps fields. How we can validate the present step fields instead of all fields?**

I am using Angular 4 with Reactive Form, I am using angular-archwizard for make multi step form, currently it allows me to go to next step without entering all value of required field, I don't want to allow that, I want to go next step if I entered value in all required field,

how can I do this ???

Following is my form

```
<aw-wizard>
  <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 1">
  <input type="text" formControlName="BillingAddressLine1" class="form-control" 
    [(ngModel)]="billingAddressLine1">
    <button type="button" awNextStep>Next Step</button>
    <button type="button" [awGoToStep]="{stepIndex: 2}">Go directly to third Step</button>
  </aw-wizard-step>
  <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 2" awOptionalStep>
    Content of Step 2
    <button type="button" awPreviousStep>Go to previous step</button>
    <button type="button" awNextStep>Go to next step</button>
  </aw-wizard-step>
  <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 3">
    Content of Step 3
    <button type="button" awPreviousStep>Previous Step</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="finishFunction()">Finish</button>
  </aw-wizard-step>
</aw-wizard>
```

I want that user should not allowed to go to the next step untill it don't enter value of BillingAddressLine1 because this field is required

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd need to tie it to the form validity then:

```
<button
  type="button"
  awNextStep
  [disabled]="yourFormName.status === 'INVALID'">Go to next step</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I am using Reactive form with Angular 4 and my form name is myForm, I have total 6 steps in my form  I have tried this but it checks for whole form's control it is not checking for particular step, 
I want to allow to go to next page if I enter data of all required field in current step 

 [disabled]="myForm.status === 'INVALID'"  is check for all the controls of my form.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[canExit]` or `[canEnter]`. [Check documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-archwizard#canexit)